# textField with css fontSize set to percentage does not scale in full screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In AS3 flash - I have a textField with a CSS in it that looks like this:

```
body {
   fontSize: 10%;
}
```

When it runs, the font is small.  When I click the full screen button, I expected the font to increase proportionally because I set it for 10%.  However, this is not working, the font stays at the same size as when not in full screen.  I have debugged the onResize event and I can see the style fontSize=10pct when I log it out.

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of % here?  I was hoping it would increase the fontSize automatically when going to full screen mode, but that does not appear to be the case.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flash ignores the percentage part of your css declaration and just sets it to 10.

heres a quote from the docs:

> font-size:
>   Only the numeric part of the value is used. Units (px, pt) are not parsed; pixels and points are equivalent.

link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000908.html

---

The only thing you can do is set the font-size manually in your "onResize" event handler.

Comment: I had read that, but I was hoping since they interpret the % to pct that the doc was incomplete or out of date.